# Draw the Line to between two objects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing  the application to match the word using the Line i have done question and answer but i want to know how to match the particular question to correct answer using the Line. i am using the Database to display the Question answer

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get the source code from this [link](https://github.com/zelox991/DrawingApp)

and to change the properties of line like line width change, color,etc go to EC189DrawingViewController in that source code and edit in following section

```
- (void)drawShapes {
//NSLog(@"In drawShapes!");

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_drawingPad.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

for(myShape *i in _collection) {
    [self drawShapesSubroutine:i contextRef:context];
    if(i.selected == true) {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]);
        float num[] = {6.0, 6.0};
        CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0, num, 2);

        CGRect rectangle;
        [self drawShapeSelector:i selectorRect: &rectangle];
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);        
        CGContextStrokePath(context);


        //tapped = true;
    }
}

if(!skipDrawingCurrentShape && (selectedIndex == -1)) {
    [self drawShapesSubroutine:_currentShape contextRef:context];
}
_drawingPad.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```